# Как обнаружить, с какого символа текс вышел за рамки label?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qlabel, wordwrap

Как мне определить с какого символа текст выходит за рамки `label`?

Начиная с **`15`** символа, текст ушёл за рамки окна.

Как перенести строку?

Пример:

```
а б в г д е е е д д  д  д  д  о  о  о  о  о  к  к  к  к 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 и т.д
```

Comment: Рамки всегда одинаковые? Или так же могут изменяться? Проще говоря, надо отслеживать размеры рамки, или они фиксированные?

Comment: У рамок размер можно сказать фиксированный, но он изменяется путём умножение на разницу размеров (Между заданными и текущими размерами)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду `PyQt5` виджет `QLabel`, то:

> wordWrap : bool
>
> Это свойство содержит политику переноса label's

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Это QLabel", self)
        label.setText("а б в г д е е е д д  д  д  д  о  о  о  о  о  к  к  к  к " 
                           "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 и т.д ")
        label.setWordWrap(True)
        
        self.setCentralWidget(label)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странно, переносится, если есть пробел. Пример: ввввввваааааапппп  (в этом моменте строка перенесётся, т.к здесь пробел) ыыыывввввфффф